# What does "Gdk-WARNING **: gdk-frame-clock: layout continuously requested, giving up after 4 tries" mean?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, pygobject, gdk

When I run the gtk3 python code using pygobject in Ubuntu 18.04, the code runs without any warnings. But when I build it on Ubuntu 16.04 for snap, I am getting these warnings:

```
Gdk-WARNING **: gdk-frame-clock: layout continuously requested, giving up after 4 tries
```

There is no part of the code that tries to refresh the screen even twice within a second(unless there is some `check_resize` events). I am unable to understand what is causing this error. I don't have a Ubuntu 16.04 with me. so I can't debug either.

### Steps to reproduce

Install the edge release from the snap.

```
sudo snap install --edge halo-weather
```

and run it.

```
halo-weather
```

It's an opensource project of a simple weather application named [Halo](https://github.com/cijo7/Halo).  Here is the [entry point python script](https://github.com/cijo7/Halo/blob/master/halo/app.py).

Can somebody give me some directions?

Comment: It doesn't throw this error for me. Using snap.

Comment: Hi @theGtknerd, thank you for taking your time trying to help me. I fixed it a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error generally means you are directly trying to modify the UI out of sync with GTK thread.

So we need to make sure that all UI updating functions are not directly called and instead queued to be called by Gtk using any of the following:

```
GLib.idle_add(callback, ...)
GLib.timeout_add(interval, callback, ...)  # X milliseconds delay
GLib.timeout_add_seconds(interval, callback, ...)  # X seconds delay
```

Hope that will help someone.