# How to install gVim with GTK3, and fixing "gdk-frame-clock: layout continuously requested"

Tags: vim, gtk, gtk3

I tried to install gVim in my WSL 2 environment using `sudo apt install vim-gtk3`.

Everything works well, but the following gdk-warning occurs when I resize a gVim window:

[image]

I haven't seen any questions about this except for [What does "Gdk-WARNING **: gdk-frame-clock: layout continuously requested, giving up after 4 tries" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53911293), but it does not help me.

Has anyone experienced the same problem or know how to solve it?

Comment: This would probably do better on [su]. [so] is about programming problems and drifts into programming tools. [su] is about general computer software which Vim and GTK definitely are.

Comment: Use [the issue tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues).